# Power query parameter as Python variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, powerbi, powerquery

I would like to export the data via python to csv and set the download file as a parameter in Power query.

I set a parameter called Export_destination = C:\Users\Name\Desktop
And I write a python script for export as follows,

```
Export_destination = "&Text.From(Export_destination)&"
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame(dataset)
data.to_csv(r'{Export_destination}\test.csv')
```

However, the script still can not work.
Does anyone have a good solution for this question?

Answer (score 0):

instead of using "&Text.From(Export_destination)&" use '"&Text.From(Export_destination)&"'.
is your parameter type is text. if it is true use '"&Export_destination&"'.